# insufficient output in Traceback of python execution

Tags: python, django, traceback

How to further troubleshoot Django issue where only built-in package files are listed in traceback output, instead of those user-created files, which does not tell what is wrong in the *.py files I created.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 423, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/checks.py", line 83, in inline_panel_model_panels_check
    errors.extend(check_panels_in_model(cls))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/checks.py", line 110, in check_panels_in_model
    context='InlinePanel model',
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/checks.py", line 110, in check_panels_in_model
    context='InlinePanel model',
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/checks.py", line 110, in check_panels_in_model
    context='InlinePanel model',
  [Previous line repeated 984 more times]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/checks.py", line 100, in check_panels_in_model
    if hasattr(cls, 'get_edit_handler'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/utils/decorators.py", line 29, in __get__
    return self[owner]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Any thoughts on how to further troubleshoot?

Comment: Note where it says `[Previous line repeated 984 more times]` refers to `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/checks.py", line 110, in check_panels_in_model`, and `wagtail` is not a built-in package, but a package that is built on top of django.

Comment: You may wish to file an issue at [wagtail's issue tracker](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues).

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the code.

Also the code already explained what's happening there. You are using wagtail decorator, you have to check how the `decorator` method works.

The error starts from last one

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/utils/decorators.py", line 29, in __get__
    return self[owner]
```

I notice your issue is with `threading` and I guess you handling with large dataset or file.

Here you can increase the rate

```
import sys, threading
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**7) # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2**27)  # new thread will get stack of such size
```

Comment: much appreciate your reply. I noticed the keyword `InlinePanel Mode`, hence commented out the line `InlinePanel("category", label="label_category")` in my codes, which helped me get rid of that error and fix the issue.